# sql server 2008 snapshot agent problem

Tags: sql-server-2008, replication

I've just installed mssql 2008 sp1 x64 on windows 7 RTM, and have the problem with creating snapshots, whenever I try to launch the snapshot agent (i.e. to setup transactional replication publication), it throws the error that 'the file is missing'. I have looked into c:\program files\microsoft sql server\100\com and there are no executable files at all, like snapshot.exe! I tried a crazy move to copy all the files from my mssql 2005 com folder, without replacing ofcourse, and now it doesn't give an error, but says 'starting' all the time, but nothing happens. (Now I have removed those files again)
I have all of the relevant features installed.

So please help me figure out what to do now! Thanks!

Dmitri.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I copied all the files from SQLServer2008_FullSP1\x64\Setup\sql_engine_core_shared_msi\PFiles\SqlServr\100\COM\ to  c:\program files\microsoft sql server\100\com and now all of the snapshots are created fine.